# Sample data set given with Magento Community Edition and having our own data

Tags: magento-community, database

I intend to develop an e-commerce solution using Magento Community Edition (free version). During Magento Community Edition installation, we need to first install sample data (given in the magento web-site) which has to be put into a new database in MySQL, which is reflected after the installation in the Magento Demo Store. 
I need to develop the e-commerce web-site from the scratch and I have given our own data to be put into the web-site. So, should I first delete the sample data and start developing the web-site, or keep the sample data and demo store as it is, and develop a new web-site with data ? Should I create a new database for this solution or can use the same existing database created for the sample data ?

Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: Are you sure you need to install the sample data? If so, why? It's not required.

Comment: In case you haven't developed a module which has made changes to database, easy and simple way would be create a new DB, don't import anything, install the same magento, by first removing local.xml in app/etc

Comment: Echoing what others have said — you can install Magento without the sample data.  I remember the wording for this was/is a little confusing — when Magento says you MUST install the sample data before installation, that only means if you want to use the sample data.  i.e. you can't install blank, and then import the samples.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the sample data and I would recommend developing our site that will eventually go to production without the sample data. It will be more difficult to try to delete it all later.